# Package latexalpha2 Error: WolframScript cannot be found, which is required to use latexalpha2

Tags: luatex, windows, linux, wolfram-mathematica, latexalpha2

Although wolframscript is fully working on the command prompt of Windows 10, the package `latexalpha2` gives this error

> Package latexalpha2 Error: WolframScript cannot be found, which is
> required to use latexalpha2.

Inspired by the comments on [this relevant question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528566/2288), the package might be designed to work on Linux devices only.

So, I hope if someone can find the required edits to the following package file to make it work with `lualatex` on Windows 10.

```
%% This is file `latexalpha2.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% latexalpha2.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% Copyright (C) 2019 by Yi Liu <me@yliu.io>
%% 
%% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions of
%% the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c of this license
%% or (at your option) any later version. The latest version of this
%% license is in:
%% 
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2006/05/20 or later.
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{latexalpha2}
  [2019/03/05 v1.1 latexalpha2]
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\RequirePackage{morewrites}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}

\newbool{ifcache}
\newbool{ifmathics}

\DeclareOption{local}{\def\la@platform{-local}}
\DeclareOption{cloud}{\def\la@platform{-cloud}}
\DeclareOption{cache}{\booltrue{ifcache}}
\DeclareOption{nocache}{\boolfalse{ifcache}}
\DeclareOption{mathics}{\booltrue{ifmathics}}

\ExecuteOptions{local,cache}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`#=12
  \catcode`&=12
  \gdef\@hashchar{#}
  \gdef\@ampchar{&}
  \gdef\backslash{\@backslashchar}
  \gdef\hash{\@hashchar}
  \makeatother
\endgroup

\def\la@codetempfile{latexalpha2_code.tmp}
\def\la@resulttempfile{}
\def\la@currcodehash{}

\newcommand{\la@cleancodetempfile}{\immediate\write18{rm -f \la@codetempfile}}
\newcommand{\la@unknownoption}[2]{\PackageError{latexalpha2}{Unknown option '#2' for \@backslashchar #1}{}}

\newcommand{\la@executewolfram}[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{\la@resulttempfile}{%
    \ifbool{ifcache}{\message{found cached output file \la@resulttempfile^^J}}{\la@executewolframcore{#1}}%
  }{\la@executewolframcore{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\la@executewolframcore}[1]{%
  \notbool{ifmathics}{%
    \def\la@wolframscript{wolframscript -file \la@codetempfile\space -print \ifblank{#1}{}{-format #1} \la@platform\space> \la@resulttempfile}%
  }{%
    \def\la@wolframscript{mathics \la@codetempfile\space> \la@resulttempfile}%
  }%
  \message{command: \la@wolframscript^^J}%
  \immediate\write18{\la@wolframscript}%
}

\newcommand{\la@writecodefile}[2]{%
  \message{------------ latexalpha2 -------------^^J}%
  \message{\notbool{ifmathics}{wolfram}{mathics} code: #1^^J}%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{\message{option: #2}}%
  \gdef\la@currcodehash{\ifxetex\mdfivesum{#1#2}\else\pdfmdfivesum{#1#2}\fi}%
  \gdef\la@resulttempfile{.latexalpha2_\la@currcodehash.out}%
  \newwrite\tempfile%
  \immediate\openout\tempfile=\la@codetempfile%
  \immediate\write\tempfile{#1}%
  \immediate\closeout\tempfile%
}

\newcommand{\la@notformathics}[1]{%
  \ifbool{ifmathics}{\PackageError{latexalpha2}{\@backslashchar #1 is not available for the Mathics mode}{}}{}%
}

\def\la@texformat{tex}
\def\la@textformat{text}
\def\la@wolframformat{wolfram}
\def\la@wolframtwoformat{wolfram2}
\def\la@pdfformat{pdf}
\def\la@pngformat{png}
\def\la@jpgformat{jpg}

\newcommand{\wolfram}[2][tex]{%
  \def\la@currformat{#1}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
  \notbool{ifmathics}{%
    \la@writecodefile{#2}{#1}%
    \ifx \la@currformat \la@texformat \la@executewolfram{TeXForm} \else
    \ifx \la@currformat \la@textformat \la@executewolfram{Text} \else
    \ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
    \la@unknownoption{wolfram}{#1}
    \fi\fi\fi
  }{%
    \ifx \la@currformat \la@texformat \la@writecodefile{Print[TeXForm[#2]]}{#1} \else
    \ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframformat \la@writecodefile{Print[#2]}{#1} \else
    \la@unknownoption{wolfram}{#1}
    \fi\fi
    \la@executewolfram{}
  }
  \input{\la@resulttempfile}%%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}

\newcommand{\wolframalpha}[2][tex]{%
  \la@notformathics{wolframalpha}%
  \def\la@currformat{#1}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
  \la@writecodefile{WolframAlpha["#2","%
    \ifx\la@currformat\la@textformat ShortAnswer\else
    \ifx\la@currformat\la@wolframtwoformat Result\else
    WolframResult\fi\fi
    "]}{#1}%
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@textformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframtwoformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@texformat \la@executewolfram{TeXForm} \else
  \la@unknownoption{wolframalpha}{#1}
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
  \input{\la@resulttempfile}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}

\newcommand{\wolframgraphics}[3][pdf]{%
  \def\la@currformat{#1}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
  \notbool{ifmathics}{%
    \la@writecodefile{#2}{#1}%
    \ifx \la@currformat \la@pdfformat \la@executewolfram{PDF} \else
    \ifx \la@currformat \la@pngformat \la@executewolfram{PNG} \else
    \ifx \la@currformat \la@jpgformat \la@executewolfram{JPEG} \else
    \la@unknownoption{wolframgraphics}{#1}
    \fi\fi\fi
    \ifx \la@currformat \la@pdfformat \immediate\write18{cp\space\la@resulttempfile\space#3.pdf} \else
    \ifx \la@currformat \la@pngformat \immediate\write18{cp\space\la@resulttempfile\space#3.png} \else
    \ifx \la@currformat \la@jpgformat \immediate\write18{cp\space\la@resulttempfile\space#3.jpg} \else
    \la@unknownoption{wolframgraphics}{#1}
    \fi\fi\fi
  }{%
    \la@writecodefile{Print[TeXForm[#2]]}{asy}
    \la@executewolfram{}
    \immediate\write18{cp\space\la@resulttempfile\space#3.asy}
  }
}

\newcommand{\wolframsolve}[2]{%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
  \def\la@solvecode{"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar begin{flalign*}"<>StringJoin@@("\@ampchar"<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][#2]]<>"="<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][\@hashchar]]<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar"\@ampchar/@(#2/.Solve[#1, #2]))<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar end{flalign*}"}
  \notbool{ifmathics}{%
    \la@writecodefile{\la@solvecode}{}%
    \la@executewolfram{Text}%
  }{%
    \la@writecodefile{Print[\la@solvecode]}{}%
    \la@executewolfram{}%
  }
  \input{\la@resulttempfile}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}

\newcommand{\wolframdsolve}[3]{%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
  \def\la@solvecode{"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar begin{flalign*}"<>StringJoin@@("\@ampchar"<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][#2]]<>"="<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][\@hashchar]]<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar"\@ampchar/@(#2/.DSolve[#1, #2, #3]))<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar end{flalign*}"}
  \notbool{ifmathics}{%
    \la@writecodefile{\la@solvecode}{}%
    \la@executewolfram{Text}%
  }{%
    \la@writecodefile{Print[\la@solvecode]}{}%
    \la@executewolfram{}%
  }
  \input{\la@resulttempfile}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}

\newcommand{\wolframtex}[2][tex]{%
  \la@notformathics{wolframtex}%
  \def\la@currformat{#1}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
  \la@writecodefile{ToExpression["\unexpanded{#2}", TeXForm]}{#1}%
  \immediate\write18{sed -i '' 's/\@backslashchar\@backslashchar/\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar/g' \la@codetempfile}%
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@texformat \la@executewolfram{TeXForm} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@textformat \la@executewolfram{Text} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
  \la@unknownoption{wolframtex}{#1}
  \fi\fi\fi
  \input{\la@resulttempfile}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}

\newcommand{\wolframanimation}[2]{%
  \la@notformathics{wolframanimation}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
  \la@writecodefile{#1}{}%
  \la@executewolfram{GIF}
  \immediate\write18{cp\space\la@resulttempfile\space#2.gif}%
  \immediate\write18{mkdir -p #2}%
  \immediate\write18{convert -coalesce #2.gif #2/frame.png}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}

\newcommand{\wolframtable}[1]{%
  \la@notformathics{wolframtable}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
  \def\la@tablecode{StringJoin@@((StringRiffle[("$"<>Slot[1]<>"$")\@ampchar/@ToString/@TeXForm/@(Slot[1]),"\space\@ampchar\space"]<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar")\@ampchar/@(#1))}%
  \la@writecodefile{\la@tablecode}{}%
  \la@executewolfram{Text}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
  \input{\la@resulttempfile}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  %^^A check if shell-escape is available
  \ifcase\pdf@shellescape
  \PackageError{latexalpha2}{Shell escape is not enabled, which is required to use latexalpha2}{}\or
  \PackageInfo{latexalpha2}{Shell escape is successfully enabled}{}\or
  \PackageError{latexalpha2}{Shell escape is not enabled, which is required to use latexalpha2}{}\fi

  %^^A check if wolframscript or mathics is available
  \immediate\write18{command -v \notbool{ifmathics}{wolframscript}{mathics}; echo $? > latexalpha2_check.tmp}%
  \newread\wsreturncodefile%
  \immediate\openin\wsreturncodefile=latexalpha2_check.tmp%
  \readline\wsreturncodefile to \wsreturncode%
  \immediate\closein\wsreturncodefile%
  %^^A https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26873
  \def\instring#1#2{TT\fi\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\in@{#1}{#2}}\x\ifin@}%
  \notbool{ifmathics}{%
    \if\instring{0}{\wsreturncode}
    \PackageInfo{latexalpha2}{WolframScript is available}{}\else
    \PackageError{latexalpha2}{WolframScript cannot be found, which is required to use latexalpha2}{}\fi
  }{%
    \if\instring{0}{\wsreturncode}
    \PackageInfo{latexalpha2}{Mathics is available}{}\else
    \PackageError{latexalpha2}{Mathics cannot be found, which is required to use the Mathics mode of latexalpha2}{}\fi
  }
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifbool{ifcache}{}{\immediate\write18{rm -f .latexalpha2_*.out}}
}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `latexalpha2.sty'.
```

Comment: why don't you try yourself? Go through the code, look for all \immediate\write18 lines and then consider if the call makes sense on windows and if not how to translate it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if I know how to do it, I wouldn't ask on this Q/A site in the first place.

Comment: you don't have to know, I don't know it either. You only need to be able to find it out and test. (I don't have wolfram, so I can't test anything at all)

Comment: It's probably sufficient to replace `wolframscript` by `C:\full\path\to\wolframscript.exe` in `\la@wolframscript` and remove the installation check in `\AtBeginDocument`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer**

An answer for question posted: adapting `latexalpha2` for windows and `lualatex` / `pdflatex`.

[image: c]

[image: xx]

This code test most of the functions of the original package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage{float}% 

\RequirePackage[cache]{latexalpha2wlua} % option cache (faster the second run) or nocache (recalculate always)

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \wolframgraphics{Plot3D[Sin[x]Cos[y],{x,-2Pi,2Pi},{y,-2Pi,2Pi}]}{Plot3Db}
    \includegraphics{Plot3Db.pdf}
    \caption{Plot 3D of $f(x,y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)$}
    \centering
\end{figure}

Laplace Transform of $t^4 sin(t)$

$$ \wolfram{LaplaceTransform[t^4 Sin[t],t,s]} $$

Generates a power series expansion

$$ \wolfram{Series[Exp[x],{x,0,5}]} $$

\bigskip    

Compton scattering for electron \bigskip

$\wolframalpha{Compton scattering for electron}$

\bigskip    

Solve the equation  $a x^2+b x+c=0$ and display the corresponding results

\wolframsolve{a x^2+b x+c==0}{x}

\newpage
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc} %set the correct number of columns!
        \toprule
        \wolframtable{Join[{{x,x^2,x^3,x^4}}, Table[{i,i^2,i^3,i^4},{i,6}]]}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Generate a table $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, $x^4$}
\end{table} 

\bigskip

The population of Shanghai is $\wolframalpha{Shanghai population}$, which
is $\wolframalpha{ratio of Shanghai population and NYC population}$ times the
population of New York City.

\bigskip

Solve differential equations $y'(x) + y(x) = a *sin(x)*y(x)*x $

\wolframdsolve{y'[x]+y[x]==a Sin[x]}{y[x]}{x}

\end{document}
```

The package, that I renamed `latexalpha2wlua`, works with windows and `lualatex`.

```
%%
%% This is file `latexalpha2wlua.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% latexalpha2.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% Copyright (C) 2019 by Yi Liu <me@yliu.io>
%% 
%% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions of
%% the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c of this license
%% or (at your option) any later version. The latest version of this
%% license is in:
%% 
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2006/05/20 or later.
%%
%% modified for windows and luatex by Simon Dispa (2021) v1.0e
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{latexalpha2wlua}[2021/01/21 v1.0d latexalpha2wlua]
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\RequirePackage{shellesc}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}%
\RequirePackage{animate}

\newbool{ifcache}

\DeclareOption{local}{\def\la@platform{-local}}
\DeclareOption{cloud}{\def\la@platform{-cloud}}
\DeclareOption{cache}{\booltrue{ifcache}}
\DeclareOption{nocache}{\boolfalse{ifcache}}

\ExecuteOptions{local}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`#=12
\catcode`&=12
\gdef\@hashchar{#}
\gdef\@ampchar{&}
\gdef\backslash{\@backslashchar}
\makeatother
\endgroup

\def\la@codetempfile{la2w_code.wls}
\def\la@resulttempfile{}
\def\la@currcodehash{}
\def\la@animaoutdir{}
\def\la@outdir{la_output}
\def\la@midrule{midrule}

\newcommand{\la@unknownoption}[2]{\PackageError{latexalpha2wlua}{Unknown option '#2' for \@backslashchar #1}{}}

\newcommand{\la@makedir}[1]{IF NOT EXIST #1 md #1}
\newcommand{\la@deldir}[1]{rd /Q /S #1 }

\newcommand{\la@executewolfram}[1]{%
\IfFileExists{\la@resulttempfile}{\ifbool{ifcache}{}{\la@executewolframcore{#1}}
}{\la@executewolframcore{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\la@executewolframcore}[1]{%
\def\la@wolframscript{wolframscript -file \la@outdir\backslash\la@codetempfile\space -print -format #1 \la@platform\space> \la@resulttempfile}%
\immediate\write18{\la@wolframscript}%
}


\newcommand{\la@writecodefile}[2]{%
\gdef\la@currcodehash{\pdf@mdfivesum{#1#2}}%%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\gdef\la@resulttempfile{\la@outdir\backslash#2_\la@currcodehash.out}%
\newwrite\tempfile%
\immediate\openout\tempfile=\la@outdir\backslash\la@codetempfile%
\immediate\write\tempfile{#1}%
\immediate\closeout\tempfile%
}

\def\la@texformat{tex}
\def\la@textformat{txt}
\def\la@wolframformat{wolfram}
\def\la@wolframtwoformat{wolfram2}
\def\la@pdfformat{pdf}
\def\la@pngformat{png}
\def\la@jpgformat{jpg}

\newcommand{\wolfram}[2][tex]{%
\message{>>>> starting wolfram (#1): please wait ...  ^^J}%
\def\la@currformat{#1}%
\la@writecodefile{#2}{#1}%
\ifx \la@currformat \la@texformat \la@executewolfram{TeXForm} \else
\ifx \la@currformat \la@textformat \la@executewolfram{txt} \else
\ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
\la@unknownoption{wolfram}{#1}
\fi\fi\fi
\input{\la@resulttempfile}%
}

\newcommand{\wolframalpha}[2][tex]{%
\message{>>>> starting wolframalpha (-> #1): please wait ...  ^^J}%
\def\la@currformat{#1}%
\la@writecodefile{WolframAlpha["#2","%
\ifx\la@currformat\la@textformat ShortAnswer\else
\ifx\la@currformat\la@wolframtwoformat Result\else
WolframResult\fi\fi
"]}{#1}%
\ifx \la@currformat \la@textformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
\ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
\ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframtwoformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
\ifx \la@currformat \la@texformat \la@executewolfram{TeXForm} \else
\la@unknownoption{wolframalpha}{#1}
\fi\fi\fi\fi
\input{\la@resulttempfile}%
}

\newcommand{\wolframgraphics}[3][pdf]{%
\message{>>>> starting wolfram #1 graphics: please wait ...  ^^J}%
\def\la@currformat{#1}%
\la@writecodefile{#2}{#1}%
\ifx \la@currformat \la@pdfformat \la@executewolfram{PDF} \else
\ifx \la@currformat \la@pngformat \la@executewolfram{PNG} \else
\ifx \la@currformat \la@jpgformat \la@executewolfram{JPEG} \else
\la@unknownoption{wolframgraphics}{#1}
\fi\fi\fi
\ifx \la@currformat \la@pdfformat \immediate\write18{copy\space\la@resulttempfile\space#3.pdf >NUL} \else
\ifx \la@currformat \la@pngformat \immediate\write18{copy\space\la@resulttempfile\space#3.png >NUL} \else
\ifx \la@currformat \la@jpgformat \immediate\write18{copy\space\la@resulttempfile\space#3.jpg >NUL} \else
\la@unknownoption{wolframgraphics}{#1}
\fi\fi\fi
}

\newcommand{\wolframsolve}[2]{%
\def\la@currformat{#2}%
\message{>>>> starting wolfram (-> tex) solve: please wait ...  ^^J}%
\la@writecodefile{"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar begin{flalign*}"<>StringJoin@@("\@ampchar"<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][#2]]<>"="<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][\@hashchar]]<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar"\@ampchar/@(#2/.Solve[#1, #2]))<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar end{flalign*}"}{}%
\la@executewolfram{txt}%
\input{\la@resulttempfile}%
}

\newcommand{\wolframdsolve}[3]{%
\message{>>>> starting wolfram (-> tex) diff. eq. solve: please wait ...  ^^J}%
\la@writecodefile{"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar begin{flalign*}"<>StringJoin@@("\@ampchar"<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][#2]]<>"="<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][\@hashchar]]<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar"\@ampchar/@(#2/.DSolve[#1, #2, #3]))<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar end{flalign*}"}{}%
\la@executewolfram{txt}%
\input{\la@resulttempfile}%
}

\newcommand{\wolframtable}[1]{%
\message{>>>> starting wolfram table: please wait ...  ^^J}%
\def\la@tablecode{StringJoin@@(%
(StringRiffle[("$"<>Slot[1]<>"$")   \@ampchar/@ToString/@TeXForm/@(Slot[1]),"\space\@ampchar\space" ]
<>  "\space\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\space\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\la@midrule\space")
\@ampchar/@(#1)     
)}%
\la@writecodefile{\la@tablecode}{tex}%
\la@executewolfram{Text}%
\input{\la@resulttempfile}%
}
    \newcommand{\wolframonlygif}[2]{%
    \message{>>>> starting wolfram only gif: please wait wait wait  ...  ^^J}%
    \la@writecodefile{#1}{gif}%
    \la@executewolfram{GIF}
    \immediate\write18{copy\space\la@resulttempfile\space #2.gif >NUL}% 
}

\newcommand{\wolframanimation}[2]{%
\message{>>>> starting wolfram animation: please wait wait wait  ...  ^^J}%
\gdef\la@animaoutdir{#2}    
\immediate\write18{\la@makedir{\la@animaoutdir}}
\la@writecodefile{#1}{gif}%
\la@executewolfram{GIF}
\immediate\write18{copy\space\la@resulttempfile\space\la@animaoutdir\backslash#2.gif >NUL}% OK
\immediate\write18{convert -coalesce \space\la@animaoutdir\backslash#2.gif #2/frame.png}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%  
\immediate\write18{\la@makedir{\la@outdir}} 
%%  Check if wolframscript is available
\immediate\write18{wolframscript -code 2+2 > la2_check.tmp}%
\newread\wsreturncodefile%
\immediate\openin\wsreturncodefile= la2_check.tmp%
\readline\wsreturncodefile to \wsreturncode%
\immediate\closein\wsreturncodefile%
%   %^^A https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26873
\def\instring#1#2{TT\fi\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\in@{#1}{#2}}\x\ifin@}%
\if\instring{4}{\wsreturncode}
\immediate\write18{del /Q la2_check.tmp >NUL} 
\PackageInfo{latexalpha2wlua}{WolframScript is available}{}\else
\PackageError{latexalpha2wlua}{WolframScript cannot be found. Required to use latexalpha2wlua}{}     
\fi
}

\AtEndDocument{%
\ifbool{ifcache}{}{\immediate\write18{\la@deldir{\la@outdir}}} 
}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `latexalpha2wlua.sty'.
```

**Notes**

**(0)** Wolfram Engine must be installed and  wolframscript must be fully working on the command prompt! Examples might be found in

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html

(1) Tested with windows 7.

(2) The file `latexalpha2wlua.sty` should be in the same directory of the `.tex` document.

(3) Tested with lualatex and pdflatex. See the MWE

(4) The code was simplified, eliminating the harmless messages.

(5) Using the option `cache` makes the recompile  much faster if the query does not change. For the time being all the output files remain in the same directory. The option `nocache` clears everything, but recalculates all the second time.

(6) To make animated GIFs with the same package see

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580062/161015

Comment: many thanks for your answer. I use lualatex all the time not pdflatex. Do you mean that your code won't work with lualatex or just works with limitations?

Comment: @Diaa  It woks with lualatex up to my MWE. Up to you to test the full functionality . I updated the answer.

Comment: It normally works with me but I don't understand why I receive many messages in texstudio like these `'command' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Could Not Find C:\Users\Diaa\Desktop\Test\latexalpha2_code.tmp` as shown here https://i.ibb.co/Fn8YcXq/image.png

Comment: They are a nuisance. Windows says it can't find the .tmp files to delete. "Apparently"  it does not affect the operation of the class. I'm tracing the origin because I also like tidier things.

Comment: Each command is deleting the temp code file (via `\la@cleancodetempfile`) twice at the start and end of the command definition. If we only keep the cleaning process at the end of each command, no error would show up. Now, I am trying to resolve the error of `command` which comes from this line `\immediate\write18{command wolframscript; echo $? > latexalpha2_check.tmp}` I think. Also, I don't know why this `\ifbool{ifcache}{}{\immediate\write18{del/Q *.out} }` doesn't delete `*out` files.

Comment: OK! The deletion `\immediate\write18{del/Q *.out}` should be in the true condition of `ifcache` not the false one `\ifbool{ifcache}{\immediate\write18{del/Q *.out} }{}`.

Comment: I fixed all the issues and will post a complementary answer tomorrow.. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have some points on your great answer: **(1)** you accidentally delete the definition `\newcommand{\la@unknownoption}[2]{\PackageError{latexalpha2}{Unknown option '#2' for #1}{}}` from your file. **(2)** For the copy command I think `copy /y` is better. **(3)** Have you intentionally removed the command `\wolframanimation`? **(4)** You forgot to move the deletion to the true condition of `ifcache` here `\ifbool{ifcache}{}{\immediate\write18{del /Q *.out >NUL} }`.

Comment: Also, I think the delete command should better be `del /f /q <the file> 2>nul`. For the sake of completeness, it would be nice to have examples of `\wolframtable`, `\wolframdsolve`, and `\wolframanimation`.

Comment: Furthermore, why does the option `cloud` fail with `\wolframalpha{Shanghai population}` and `\wolframalpha{ratio of Shanghai population and NYC population}`?

Comment: `\wolframtable` and  `\wolframdsolve` examples are included in the MWE, I did not test  `\wolframanimation` yet.

Comment: `\RequirePackage[cache]{latexalpha2wlua}` keeps output files for reuse. `\RequirePackage[nocache]{latexalpha2wlua} ` deletes them on exit

Comment: May I know why you used extension `wsl` for the temporary code file?

Comment: Its is useful for debugging. I some cases it can fed into wolfrascript from the console.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own take on Simon Dispa's great [original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579254/2288).

```
%% This is file `latexalpha2Win.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% latexalpha2.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% Copyright (C) 2019 by Yi Liu <me@yliu.io>
%% 
%% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions of
%% the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c of this license
%% or (at your option) any later version. The latest version of this
%% license is in:
%% 
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2006/05/20 or later.
%% modified for windows and luatex by Simon Dispa (2021) 
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579254/2288
%% and Diaa 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{latexalpha2Win}
  [2021/01/19 v1.0 latexalpha2Win]
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\RequirePackage{shellesc}

\newbool{ifcache}

\DeclareOption{local}{\def\la@platform{-local}}
\DeclareOption{cloud}{\def\la@platform{-cloud}}
\DeclareOption{cache}{\booltrue{ifcache}}
\DeclareOption{nocache}{\boolfalse{ifcache}}

\ExecuteOptions{local,cache}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`#=12
  \catcode`&=12
  \gdef\@hashchar{#}
  \gdef\@ampchar{&}
  \gdef\backslash{\@backslashchar}
  \makeatother
\endgroup

\def\la@codetempfile{latexalpha2_code.tmp}
\def\la@resulttempfile{}
\def\la@currcodehash{}

\newcommand{\la@cleancodetempfile}{\immediate\write18{del /F \la@codetempfile}}
\newcommand{\la@unknownoption}[2]{\PackageError{latexalpha2}{Unknown option '#2' for #1}{}}

\newcommand{\la@executewolfram}[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{\la@resulttempfile}{
    \ifbool{ifcache}{\message{found cached output file \la@resulttempfile^^J}}{\la@executewolframcore{#1}}
  }{\la@executewolframcore{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\la@executewolframcore}[1]{%
  \def\la@wolframscript{wolframscript -file \la@codetempfile\space -print \ifblank{#1}{}{-format #1} \la@platform\space> \la@resulttempfile}%
  \message{command: \la@wolframscript^^J}%
  \immediate\write18{\la@wolframscript}%
}

\newcommand{\la@writecodefile}[2]{%
  \message{------------ latexalpha2 x-------------^^J}%
  \message{wolfram code: #1^^J}%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{\message{option: #2}}%
  \gdef\la@currcodehash{\pdf@mdfivesum{#1#2}}%
  \gdef\la@resulttempfile{.latexalpha2_\la@currcodehash.out}%
  \newwrite\tempfile%
  \immediate\openout\tempfile=\la@codetempfile%
  \immediate\write\tempfile{#1}%
  \immediate\closeout\tempfile%
}

\def\la@texformat{tex}
\def\la@textformat{text}
\def\la@wolframformat{wolfram}
\def\la@wolframtwoformat{wolfram2}
\def\la@pdfformat{pdf}
\def\la@pngformat{png}
\def\la@jpgformat{jpg}

\newcommand{\wolfram}[2][tex]{%
  \def\la@currformat{#1}%
  \la@writecodefile{#2}{#1}%
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@texformat \la@executewolfram{TeXForm} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@textformat \la@executewolfram{Text} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
  \la@unknownoption{wolfram}{#1}
  \fi\fi\fi
  \input{\la@resulttempfile}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}

\newcommand{\wolframalpha}[2][tex]{%
  \def\la@currformat{#1}%
  \la@writecodefile{WolframAlpha["#2","%
    \ifx\la@currformat\la@textformat ShortAnswer\else
    \ifx\la@currformat\la@wolframtwoformat Result\else
    WolframResult\fi\fi
    "]}{#1}%
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@textformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframtwoformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@texformat \la@executewolfram{TeXForm} \else
  \la@unknownoption{wolframalpha}{#1}
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
  \input{\la@resulttempfile}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}

\newcommand{\wolframgraphics}[3][pdf]{%
  \def\la@currformat{#1}%
  \la@writecodefile{#2}{#1}%
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@pdfformat \la@executewolfram{PDF} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@pngformat \la@executewolfram{PNG} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@jpgformat \la@executewolfram{JPEG} \else
  \la@unknownoption{wolframgraphics}{#1}
  \fi\fi\fi
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@pdfformat \immediate\write18{copy \la@resulttempfile #3.pdf} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@pngformat \immediate\write18{copy \la@resulttempfile #3.png} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@jpgformat \immediate\write18{copy \resulttempfile #3.jpg} \else
  \la@unknownoption{wolframgraphics}{#1}
  \fi\fi\fi
  \la@cleancodetempfile
}

\newcommand{\wolframsolve}[2]{%
  \la@writecodefile{"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar begin{flalign*}"<>StringJoin@@("\@ampchar"<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][#2]]<>"="<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][\@hashchar]]<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar"\@ampchar/@(#2/.Solve[#1, #2]))<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar end{flalign*}"}{}%
  \la@executewolfram{Text}%
  \input{\la@resulttempfile}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}

\newcommand{\wolframdsolve}[3]{%
  \la@writecodefile{"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar begin{flalign*}"<>StringJoin@@("\@ampchar"<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][#2]]<>"="<>ToString[ToExpression["TeXForm"][\@hashchar]]<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar"\@ampchar/@(#2/.DSolve[#1, #2, #3]))<>"\@backslashchar\@backslashchar end{flalign*}"}{}%
  \la@executewolfram{Text}%
  \input{\la@resulttempfile}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}

\newcommand{\wolframtex}[2][tex]{%
  \def\la@currformat{#1}%
  \la@writecodefile{ToExpression["\unexpanded{#2}", TeXForm]}{#1}%
  \immediate\write18{sed -i '' 's/\@backslashchar\@backslashchar/\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar\@backslashchar/g' \la@codetempfile}%
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@texformat \la@executewolfram{TeXForm} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@textformat \la@executewolfram{Text} \else
  \ifx \la@currformat \la@wolframformat \la@executewolfram{} \else
  \la@unknownoption{wolframtex}{#1}
  \fi\fi\fi
  \input{\la@resulttempfile}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}

\newcommand{\wolframanimation}[2]{%
  \la@writecodefile{#1}{}%
  \la@executewolfram{GIF}
  \immediate\write18{copy \space\la@resulttempfile\space#2.gif}%
  \immediate\write18{md #2}%
  \immediate\write18{convert -coalesce #2.gif #2/frame.png}%
  \la@cleancodetempfile%
}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  % Check if shell-escape is available
  \ifcase\pdf@shellescape
  \PackageError{latexalpha2}{Shell escape is not enabled, which is required to use latexalpha2}{}\or
  \PackageInfo{latexalpha2}{Shell escape is successfully enabled}{}\or
  \PackageError{latexalpha2}{Shell escape is not enabled, which is required to use latexalpha2}{}\fi

  % Check if wolframscript is available
  \immediate\write18{where wolframscript >latexalpha2_check.tmp 2>nul}%
  % https://stackoverflow.com/a/35408403/2849383
  %\immediate\write18{where /q wolframscript \ampchar echo \@percentchar ERRORLEVEL\@percentchar > latexalpha2_check.tmp}%
  % https://superuser.com/a/1618520/452161
  % https://superuser.com/a/718194/452161
  % https://stackoverflow.com/a/25696405/2849383
  \newread\wsreturncodefile%
  \immediate\openin\wsreturncodefile=latexalpha2_check.tmp%
  \readline\wsreturncodefile to \wsreturncode%
  \immediate\closein\wsreturncodefile%
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26873
  \def\instring#1#2{TT\fi\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\in@{#1}{#2}}\x\ifin@}%
  \if\instring{{wolframscript.exe}}{\wsreturncode}
  \PackageInfo{latexalpha2}{WolframScript is available}{}
  \immediate\write18{del /F latexalpha2_check.tmp}\else
  \immediate\write18{del /F latexalpha2_check.tmp}
  \PackageError{latexalpha2}{WolframScript cannot be found, which is required to use latexalpha2}{}
  \fi
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifbool{ifcache}{\immediate\write18{del/Q *.out}}{ }
}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `latexalpha2Win.sty'.
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.