# How to use a Mathematica plot in LaTex as a figure?

Tags: graphics, plot, graphs, wolfram-mathematica, latexalpha2

How can I insert this Mathematica plot in LaTex as a figure?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{latexalpha2}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\wolframgraphics{Plot[{Log[ x], 1*(x - 1), 1.5*(x - 1), 2*(x - 1), 2.5*(x - 1), 
  3*(x - 1)}, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 750, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick, Dashing[None]}, {Red, 
    Dashing[None]}, {Black, Dashing[None]}, {Black, 
    Dashing[None]}, {Black, Dashing[None]}, {Black, Dashing[None]}}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", None}, {None, "Fraction susceptible"}}, 
 FrameTicks -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, -4}]}{SIR without vital dynamics picture}
\includegraphics{SIR without vital dynamics picture.pdf}
\caption{Plot of $f(x,y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)$}
\centering
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:

Is this the woflramScript?

[image]

Errors:

[image]

Using the PDF method(I stretched the image), I have the following:

[image]

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics.

Comment: You can considerate to use also this specific package for Wolfram
Language : `latexalpha2`. I add the link: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/latexalpha2/latexalpha2.pdf.

Comment: @Sebastiano : I get this error when trying to use the package you mention: "! Package latexalpha2 Error: Shell escape is not enabled, which is required to use latexalpha2."

Comment: @Math The reason can be anything: if you have installed the package, what is the your LaTeX distribuition, etc. Please, can you add your minimal working example with more informations? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano Added

Comment: @Sebastiano I am also using "quick build" so I don't know if this causes issues, I tried using PDFLaTex but same issues. Also I haven't called my file "pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex"

Comment: @Math In the meanwhile there are many packages that can you omit. I not can reproduce the problem :-(....however..+1 for your efforts. Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @SimonDispa I tried the pdf method, the image doesn't look good, you can barely see the axis labels! maybe I need you use your method again!

Comment: See the update to configure the tex editor. It looks you are using Texmaker

Comment: @SimonDispa I think I have it figured out now using a different method :) thank you for your input Sir!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `latexalpha2wlua.sty`  from [latexalpha ported to windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579254/161015)

(1) Wolfram Engine must be installed and wolframscript must be fully working on the command prompt! (free version). [WolframScript (for the Command Line)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/?source=nav)

Try `wolframscript -version`. You should get `WolframScript 1.5.0 for Windows-x86-64` or similar.

(2) The file `latexalpha2wlua.sty` should be in the same directory of the `.tex` document.

(3)  `latexalpha2wlua` loads all the necessary packages for this graph.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{latexalpha2wlua}

\begin{document}    

\wolframgraphics{Plot[{Log[ x], 1*(x - 1), 1.5*(x - 1), 2*(x - 1), 2.5*(x - 1), 
        3*(x - 1)}, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 750, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick, Dashing[None]}, {Red, 
            Dashing[None]}, {Black, Dashing[None]}, {Black, 
            Dashing[None]}, {Black, Dashing[None]}, {Black, Dashing[None]}}, 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"y", None}, {None, "Fraction susceptible"}}, 
    FrameTicks -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, -4}]}{SIR.pdf}
        
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=.7]{SIR.pdf}
        \caption{Plot of $f(x,y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)$}
        \centering
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

Configure your tex editor:

pdflatex: => `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode   -shell-escape %.tex`

or

lualatex: => `lualatex.exe -synctex=1   -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape  %.tex`

**TeXstudio**: Options > Configure TexStudio

[image: ts]

Then > Build & View or F5

[image: ts2]

Texmaker: Options > Configure Texmaker

[image: tm]

Then > Run

[image: TM2]

Comment: I'm a amateur in computing so I'm a bit lost :( What am I supposed to do?

Comment: @Math  If you handle Mathematica, you are way ahead!

Download and install the free version of wolframscript.  It will install the Wolfram Engine on your machine at the same time.

You will be asked to register and will receive a free license.

Open the windows command (`cmd.exe`) and at the command prompt (like `c:>` in Windows) type `wolframscript -version` to test that the installation is ok and activated. It takes several seconds to answer the first time. Follow up to step 2.

Comment: for some reason its blocked on my university PC. I will try get it sorted out soon then message back! thank you for your answer by the way :)

Comment: @Math If you are using the Mathematica license of the uni ask how to run wolframscript from the PC.

Comment: I will ask., thank you!

Comment: Is this the script? I will attach a photo in the question.

Comment: @Math This is the full Mathematica! (The script runs on the command prompt. ). Your  simplest way is to generate the graph, export as a pdf and then use it in a LaTeX document: from `\begin{figure}` to `\end{figure}` only. Add  only `\usepackage{graphicx}`. `latexalpha2wlua` is not  longer needed

Comment: I did get the "WolframScript 1.6.0 for Windows-x86-64" on the command prompt. I saved the "latexalpha2wlua" file(as a mathematica notebook file(?)) in the same folder as the latex file. what shall I do next?

Comment: @Math Run my code as any other LaTeX document.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of errors when running it as "quick build" with "view pdf" I'll show in the question

Comment: @Math Try only my code. Your looks much more elaborate and might be conflicts between packages. As I said before: generate only the figure, with the full Mathematica or with my code and then import the result in your document. It does not make sense to recalculate the graph every time.

Comment: running only your latexalpha2wlua codes gives the errors shown in the question

Comment: @Math It runs fine with windows 7 and 10 in a local PC. On what operating system are you running? In your local machine or in the cloud?

Comment: I'm using windows 10. its a university PC so I assume a local PC. the latexalpha2wlua filed should be saved as just "latexalpha2wlua" which will generate all the other files(.tex, .sty etc) correct? well actually since I have errors, its not generating the rest..

Comment: @Math It should be named  `latexalpha2wlua.sty`  NOT .tex!

Comment: still getting errors! When we run the latexalpha2wlua, what should we see?

Comment: @Math Leave only my code and the latexalpha2wlua.sty in a directory and try again.

Comment: what shall i run the file as? "quick build" with "view pdf"? or..?

Comment: @Math like any other tex file you compile

Comment: "could not start command. pdflatex - synctex=1 - interaction = nonstopmode %.tex"

Comment: I give up hahaha, is there any other method?

Comment: @Math (1) Use the full Mathematica you already have access to generate the figure  as a pdf and then use it in the LaTeX document. (2) Ask some local TeX expert. The solution I posted was tested  by many others.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for helping though, appreciate it :)